# Illegal Component State Exception from JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

my program uses an `xml` file to determine what info is displayed on the GUI. I thought it would be nice to add a file chooser so you can select the xml file more easily, then having to rename it to the hard coded name. When the gui Launches it is set to undecorated so that it is full screen. However, once I added the `JFileChooser` it does not work and returns:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
```

How can I go about fixing this?

This is what I have at the `JFileChooser` area:

```
 JFileChooser FE = new JFileChooser();
    int status = FE.showOpenDialog(FB);
    if(status==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        if (FE.getSelectedFile().exists())
        {
            f=FE.getSelectedFile();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Finds the file and parses the file into a document
        //File fXmlFile = new File("OPEXDataVisualizationScript.xml");
        File fXmlFile = f;
```

Comment: show what FB looks like? Also, naming regular object with all uppercase is very misleading.

Comment: Im not sure what information you will get out of FB. It is just my GUI class that puts all the information together. My main class is seperate which calls the FrameBuilder constructor, and sets it to undecorated and then visible

Comment: one that I can't get from what I see. Still, this is your problem not mine and you can go work it out any way you wish :)

Comment: Does changing it to `int status = FE.showOpenDialog(FB.this)` fix it by any chance?

Comment: I think `null` is also a valid parameter for `showOpenDialog`

Comment: Nope, Im pretty sure its an issue of getting rid of the file chooser completely after it is closed, but I dont know how to do that. Zubergu, I'm just saying that I dont think the issue is in there. That class just builds a JFrame. As I said, it worked fine before I added the JFileChooser, or when I dont set Undecorated to true. So the interaction is between those two.

Comment: @moarCoffee Worked great setting null as the parameter, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @moarCoffee or you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful.